# Updating a Google Cloud SQL Database instance

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I have a deployed `Cloud SQL Database` instance running right now and it works fine. I am able to access and use it via my `PHP` `Google App Engine` app. I also have a local SQL Database for development.

Locally, I have made some changes to the structure of the database (added new columns) and would like to push those changes to the deployed app.

When I try to do this via the documented method on the App Engine site, I get an error saying the import failed for an unknown reason.

I am using a `.sql` dump made by `PhpMyAdmin` and have done this successfully for the initial import. I made sure to include `USE DATABASE NAME` in the dump.

Any ideas as to why it's failing? What is the best way to update a Cloud SQL Database? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy way is to request an IP, whitelist the IP you are connecting from ([link](https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/docs/access-control#appaccess)) and use the MySQL client ([link](https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/docs/mysql-client)). Over IP you can also use GUI tools like MySQL Workbench, Toad, SQuirrel SQL and others ([link](https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/docs/admin-tools)).

Answer (score 0):

You can set up phpMyAdmin as a different version of your application using the instructions here: https://gae-php-tips.appspot.com/2013/05/26/setting-up-phpmyadmin-on-app-engine/  That would probably be the easiest way of updating a Cloud SQL database...

Comment: I like this option best, but I can't seem to get it to work... I works locally but when I push it to production, the page is blank.

Comment: Razvan's method is probably easier than the one I mentioned